# Trying to find volatility in R but my code won't work

Tags: r, finance, yahoo-finance, volatility

I'm using this following code to  find the volatility of Tesla:

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)

Tesla <-  getSymbols("TSLA", src = "yahoo", from = "2014-10-01", to = "2019-11-25", auto.assign = FALSE)

vol.tesla <- volatility(Tesla[ ,6])


graf_vol_tesla <- ggplot(vol.tesla, aes(x = index(vol.tesla), y = vol.tesla))+ geom_line(color = "violetred4") +
  ggtitle("volatility Tesla") + xlab("Date") + ylab("Volatility") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %y", date_breaks = "9 months")

graf_vol_tesla
```

However, it comes this as the output instead of the image. Anybody knows how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

> 'Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type xts/zoo. Defaulting to continuous. Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only'

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert your `index(vol.tesla)` to a valid date object so that ggplot can plot it. Use `as.Date` to do this as shown below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

Tesla <-  getSymbols("TSLA", src = "yahoo", from = "2014-10-01", to = "2019-11-25", auto.assign = FALSE)

vol.tesla <- volatility(Tesla[ ,6])

graf_vol_tesla <- ggplot(vol.tesla, aes(x = as.Date(index(vol.tesla)), 
                                        y = vol.tesla))+ geom_line(color = "violetred4") +
  ggtitle("volatility Tesla") + xlab("Date") + ylab("Volatility") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %y", date_breaks = "9 months")


graf_vol_tesla
```

[image]

Comment: @OmarCharmingKhodr excellent to hear. if it works, please accept the answer so others know it solved your problem (checkmark beneath the up/down vote)